# How do you use the click event properly to call another function within the class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I was confused on how to use the click event in order to call another function within the class.

```
$.fn.imageareaselect(image)
{ 
this.click(function(){
$.fn.pinpointImage.add(image);
});
}
```

The selector that is passed into this function is an image.  I wan't to make it so when you click the image it calls that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's kinda funny about passing an HTML element when you'd expect a jQuery one.  try using `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Also, jQuery functions like to take functions as params, but i'm not sure exactly what this code is trying to do now.  The first "(image)" should probably be "= function(image)" instead.